# Get the next Datetime thats greater than value

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Get the next available time from a table for the same Type thats greater than the pickuptime available for the type. I tried using the FIRST_VALUE function but that doesn't seem to work well.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test1;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Test1
(
    Type        VARCHAR(50),
    Pickup_Time TIMESTAMP,
    INSERT_TIME      TIMESTAMP
);
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test2;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE Test2
(
    Type VARCHAR(50),
    TIMEFRAME  TIMESTAMP
);


INSERT INTO Test1
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 09:00:00.000000', '2020-11-01 06:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test1
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 11:00:00.000000', '2020-11-02 05:00:00.000000');


INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 01:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 02:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 03:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 04:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 05:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 06:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 07:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 08:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 09:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 10:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 11:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 12:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 13:00:00.000000');


INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-01 01:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-01 02:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-01 03:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-01 04:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-01 05:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 06:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 07:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 08:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 09:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 10:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 11:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 12:00:00.000000');
INSERT INTO Test2
VALUES ('CAT', '2020-11-02 13:00:00.000000');


SELECT DISTINCT TT.*,
                FIRST_VALUE(CT.TIMEFRAME)
                OVER (PARTITION BY TT.Type ORDER BY TIMEFRAME rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
FROM Test1 TT
         INNER JOIN Test2 CT on TT.Type = CT.Type
    AND TT.Pickup_Time < CT.TIMEFRAME;
```

The following query provides me the required output as desired

```
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|type|pickup_time               |insert_time               |first_value               |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|MAN |2020-11-01 09:00:00.000000|2020-11-01 06:00:00.000000|2020-11-01 10:00:00.000000|
|CAT |2020-11-02 11:00:00.000000|2020-11-02 05:00:00.000000|2020-11-02 12:00:00.000000|
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

But when I do another insert for the type MAN with a different time and try to run the same SQL statement it doesn't meet my criteria

```
INSERT INTO Test1
VALUES ('MAN', '2020-11-01 03:00:00.000000', '2020-11-01 01:00:00.000000');



+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|type|pickup_time               |insert_time               |first_value               |
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
|MAN |2020-11-01 03:00:00.000000|2020-11-01 01:00:00.000000|2020-11-01 04:00:00.000000|
|MAN |2020-11-01 09:00:00.000000|2020-11-01 06:00:00.000000|2020-11-01 04:00:00.000000|
|CAT |2020-11-02 11:00:00.000000|2020-11-02 05:00:00.000000|2020-11-02 12:00:00.000000|
+----+--------------------------+--------------------------+--------------------------+
```

Instead of **2020-11-01 04:00:00.000000** the value should have been **2020-11-01 10:00:00.000000** for the second MAN entry above.

Is First_Value the right option to be used here if yes how to derive the logic if or which is the best function that can be used to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error happens because you have 2 entries for `MAN` but you just partition by `type` and therefore both entries are handled the same, you need to partition by `Pickup_Time` or `ÌNSERT_TIME`:

```sql
FIRST_VALUE(CT.TIMEFRAME)
                OVER (PARTITION BY TT.Type,TT.Pickup_Time ORDER BY TIMEFRAME rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following)
```

This will generate:

```
type    pickup_time insert_time first_value
MAN 2020-11-01 03:00:00 2020-11-01 01:00:00 2020-11-01 04:00:00
CAT 2020-11-02 11:00:00 2020-11-02 05:00:00 2020-11-02 12:00:00
MAN 2020-11-01 09:00:00 2020-11-01 06:00:00 2020-11-01 10:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Philipp, sorry for the delayed response was testing it with my dataset and it works perfectly 